# filtrar por rango de fechas Eloquent laravel condicionalmente

Tags: laravel, eloquent, busqueda-rango-de-fechas

estoy intentando realizar una vista en la cual me lista los pagos recibidos, esta vista es necesario que tenga distitos tipos de filtro, entre los cuales por ejemplo: estado, fecha desde, fecha hasta...etc.

La idea es que el usuario pueda filtrar pagos que han sido recibidos desde cierto rango de tiempo, por ejmplo los ultimos 7 dias (fechadesde = 17-02-2023, fecha hasta hoy = 24-02-2023), esto siempre y cuando ingrese fechas, para esto tengo una funcion when en mi consulta que valida que se hayan enviado fechas para filtrar.

la funcion de mi controlador es la siguiente:

```
public function filtroMovimientos(Request $request){
    $idCajero = $request->cajero;
    $idMetodoPago = $request->metodopago;
    $fechadesde = $request->fechadesde;
    $fechahasta = $request->fechahasta;
    $idCaja = $request->idcaja;
    $idDetalleCaja = $request->iddetallecaja;
    $existeFecha = false;
    if($fechadesde!==null && $fechahasta!==null){
        $existeFecha = true;
    }
    $pagos = Pago::with('MetodoPago')
    ->with('Cajero')
    ->with('Documento')
    ->with('Anulacion')
    ->when($request->cajero, function ($query, $idCajero) {
        $query->where('pagos.idUser','=',$idCajero);
    })->when($request->metodopago, function ($query,$idMetodoPago) {
        $query->where('pagos.idMetodoPago','=', $idMetodoPago);
    })->when($request->idcaja, function ($query,$idCaja) {
        $query->where('pagos.idCaja','=', $idCaja);
    })->when($request->iddetallecaja, function ($query,$idDetalleCaja) {
        $query->where('pagos.idDetalleCaja','=', $idDetalleCaja);
    })
    ->when($existeFecha, function ($query,$fechadesde, $fechahasta) {
        $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$fechadesde, $fechahasta]);
    })
    ->get();
    return $pagos;
  }
```

## El problema

Cuando hago la validacion de la siguiente forma:

```
->when($existeFecha, function ($query,$fechadesde, $fechahasta) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$fechadesde, $fechahasta]);
})
```

Responde con el siguiente error:

> "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\PagoController::App\Http\Controllers{closure}(), 2 passed in C:...\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Concerns\BuildsQueries.php on line 91 and exactly 3 expected"

Y cuando lo intento de esta otra forma:

```
->when($existeFecha, function ($query,$request) {
        $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$request->fechadesde, $fecha->fechahasta]);
})
```

> Este es el error:"Trying to get property of non-object"

Siendo que si recibo los parametros solicitados :

```
{
"cajero": "0",
"metodopago": "0",
"fechadesde": "2023-02-18",
"fechahasta": "2023-02-23"
}
```

## Pregunta

Hay alguna otra forma de pasar los parametros para completar el filtro entre fechas?

Comment: Por lo que veo estas comparando varchar con timestamps, ya convertiste tus variables en una instancia de Carbon?

Comment: Proba con `use`: `->when($existeFecha, function ($query) use ($fechadesde, $fechahasta) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$fechadesde, $fechahasta]);
})`